# How to use custom form fields for model fields in the Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I want to have the Django admin use a custom form field for the input of some fields.

Until now I made a custom model field that has the form field bound to it which works great but it introduces an unecessary model field that does not add any benefit.

I guess it can be done somehow using a custom admin form (see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: What don't you understand about that linked example? Seems perfectly clear: define your form with the custom field, and set that as the form for the admin class. What's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_field = MyCustomFormField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. I didn't know you can just overwrite form fields.

Comment: Actually, this method **does not work** -- only on regular `Form`s. If one wants to overwrite fields on a `ModelForm`, this has to be done in the Meta class. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: @jnns: Weird, the ModelForm part is taken almost verbatim from the Django doc page you have linked.